# Javascript - Change iframe src with switch

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been struggling with this for two days now. I've been asked to build a sort of log in page. It doesn't have to provide any actual security, it's purpose is just to direct people to different sites based on the code they enter. I've got the switch working and it will fire the alerts when the appropriate number is sent through the form, but when I give it the number that should update my iframe src, nothing happens. I'm thoroughly confused, I've got this same code working to update an iframe from a button press, but it simply will not work here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(IMAGES/bgTile.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.pageFrame {
 padding: 0px;
 height: 797px;
 width: 1809px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
.loginForm {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 211px;
 height: 74px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -105.5px;
 margin-top: 42px;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 21px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 z-index: 2;
}
.submitButton {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function runLogin(form) {
 var login = form.dealerID.value;
 switch(login) {
     case "1":
   loadDealer("0");
         break;
     case "2":
         alert("this");
         break;
     case "3":
         alert("that");
         break;
     default:
         alert("the other thing");;
         break;
 }
}

var dealershipsArray = [
"NULL_IMAGES/filmstripNull.html"
];

function loadDealer(i) {
 var dealership = document.getElementById("dealerContainer");
 dealership.src = dealershipsArray[i];
}
//-->
</script>

<body>
<iframe id="dealerContainer" class="pageFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe>
<div class="lutherLogo"></div>
<div id="loginBox" class="loginForm"><form name="myForm" onsubmit="runLogin(this)">
    Please Enter Your Dealer Display Code<br>
      <input type=TEXT value="" name="dealerID">
      <div class="submitButton"><input type=BUTTON value="Submit" name="myButton"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it work if you change loadDealer("0"); to loadDealer(0);

Comment: Very inappropriate tricky way to offend everyone.

Comment: oh, woops...sorry, I was venting my frustration with those alerts...I thought I changed them before I uploaded here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working version.

I did fixes in two places:

- return false from the submit handler, otherwise form submits and refreshes  itself
- the submit button should be of type="submit" otherwise handler won't be called

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Luther Automotive Display Ad Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-image: url(IMAGES/bgTile.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pageFrame {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 797px;
  width: 1809px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.lutherLogo {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(IMAGES/lutherLogo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 117px;
  height: 72px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -58.5px;
  margin-top: -36px;
}
.loginForm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 211px;
  height: 74px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -105.5px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.submitButton {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function runLogin(form) {
  var login = form.dealerID.value;
  switch(login) {
      case "1":
      loadDealer("0");
          break;
      case "2":
          alert("foo");
          break;
      case "3":
          alert("bar");
          break;
      default:
          alert("foo bar");
          break;
  }
  return false;
}

var dealershipsArray = [
"NULL_IMAGES/filmstripNull.html"
];

function loadDealer(i) {
  var dealership = document.getElementById("dealerContainer");
  dealership.src = dealershipsArray[i];
}
//-->
</script>

<body>
<iframe id="dealerContainer" class="pageFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe>
<div class="lutherLogo"></div>
<div id="loginBox" class="loginForm"><form name="myForm" onsubmit="runLogin(this)">
    Please Enter Your Dealer Display Code<br>
      <input type=TEXT value="" name="dealerID">
      <div class="submitButton"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="myButton"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'm still pretty new to Javascript but I'm the only one in the office who knows any so these projects just end up in my lap. Also, sorry about the alerts, I was venting some frustration and I though I had changed them before I uploaded here, but I guess I forgot.